# 'npm start' works but 'node ./bin/www' doesn't

Tags: node.js, git, bash, npm

recently I changed my computer, and then I had to configure everything again, install Git, Node, Mongo, etc...

In my project I had this folder called `/api`, which a lot of "modules". In other folders, I call this modules with `require("module-name")`. For this I had to set the `NODE_PATH` to the matching folder.

In my `package.json` I had this `"scripts": { "start": "node ./bin/www" }`.

So, here's the thing, when I run `npm start` everything works properly, but when I run `node ./bin/www` shows `Cannot find module 'module-name'`, but the module is there and the `NODE_PATH` too.

There's'any difference between `npm start` and normally `node` commands? Do you have any idea why this is happening?

I suspect that the problem might be the Terminal. I'm using Git Bash on Windows 10.

Comment: What about `\node ./bin/www`?

Comment: omg! works! Do you know why?

Comment: Looks that works already but I recommend you to add git to the path, install Cmder, etc... Here is a chapter of Totally Tooling Tips https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msCUKTdBzg4&list=PLOU2XLYxmsILKwwASNS0xgfcmakbK_8JZ&index=3

Comment: @daymannovaes the output of `which node` will tell you what `node` is. Seems like you have it aliased to something incompatible.  `npm start` will just run the command `node` rather than whatever alias you have.

Comment: Now everything makes sense, thanks @ExplosionPills. And Thanks too Daniel, I loved the tips!